# Configuring each git branch to a specific folder

Tags: git, web-hosting, git-branch

I am hosting a webapp on my linux server. On my local system and my github account, I have three branches -> master, develop and test. I would like to have three urls on my server pointing to each branch as follows

1. production.domainName.com pointing to master branch
2. develop.domainName.com pointing to develop branch
3. test.domainName.com pointing to test branch

I have configured my DNS settings for the three subdomains as above to point to three different directories on my server. Is it possible to configure git to save the data from one specific branch in each directory?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can have each directory be a distinct clone of the git repository, and they each will have 'their' branch checked out, and pull from github on their own schedule.

Be aware that with this sort of deployment you are exposing your entire git history to anyone on the web that thinks of adding '/.git' to the end of your url, unless you configure your web server to exclude those files. You may want to consider a script to rsync a specific branch to the right directory, excluding the .git directory. In other words, consider keeping your VCS separate from your deployment method.

Answer (score 1):

I would create repos on your server, for in the parent directory of your prod, dev and test directories (further referred as `parent_path`).

First, ssh into your server - `ssh user_name@server.url`, then cd to `parent_path` - and then

```
mkdir test.git
cd test.git
git init --bare
```

Then, add a post-receive hook to copy your codez to your appropriate directories, like this:

```
echo "#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=../test_directory/ git checkout -f" >> hooks/post-receive
```

Oh, and make the hook executable with `chmod +x hooks/post-receive`

Do that for `dev.git` and `prod.git` as well (pay attention to mention correct directory in post-receive hook - that's the dir to which your domains are pointing).

Done for now, back on local - add these as remotes:

```
git remote add test ssh://user_name@server.url/parent_path/test.git
git remote add dev ssh://user_name@server.url/parent_path/dev.git
git remote add prod ssh://user_name@server.url/parent_path/prod.git
```

Boom, all you need to do now is check out your desired branch, and push to the appropriate remote.

Comment: Hi, for some this works if I have only one remote. If I have multiple remotes, I get an error. The following is the output.

`System$ git push remote-dev development

Counting objects: 1718, done.

Delta compression using up to 2 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (1223/1223), done.

Writing objects: 100% (1718/1718), 23.62 MiB | 111.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 1718 (delta 509), reused 1651 (delta 446)

remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

To ssh://aws/~/fams-dev.git

 * [new branch]      development -> development`

Comment: The following is my .git/config file

`System$ cat config
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 logallrefupdates = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/fams/fams.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "development"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/development
[branch "staging"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/staging
[remote "remote-dev"]
 url = ssh://aws/~/fams-dev.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote-dev/*`

Comment: I am able to push the master branch successfully to any folder. I think the problem is that when I do a git init, there is no development branch in the git directory and hence I am unable to push the development branch, I believe.

Comment: Hmm, I think your last comment is pretty close - here's more info on it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/fANub3OD40E. As it has no issues receiving `master` branch, why don't you try pushing your dev and test branches to corresponding remotes' master branches? Like this: `git push remote-dev development:master` and `git push test-dev test:master`? You know saying `git push remote_name branch_name` is a convenient shorthand for `git push remote_name local_branch_name:remote_branch_name` - but you can tell it to push any branch to any branch explicitly :)

Comment: Also, your remote might complain with `[remote rejected] foo -> master (branch is currently checked out)` - but it gives you instructions to fix it in the warning message (`ssh` into your remote, `cd` into each of the `.git` folders and run `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch warn` - and try pushing again :)